# Titanium access a model from other controller

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I learned that is this how to access a model from other controller,
    var book = Alloy.Models.instance('book');

And this is how to access a property of a model,
    var name = book.get('name');

However in the console,the name logs [INFO] :  { } , meaning this doesn't get its property value, and ofcourse the model has already a data saved on it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to fetch the collection first:

```
var books = Alloy.Collections.book;
books.fetch();
```

This will load all the models from the collection so you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

although the above works, there are a few addtional points here.

- the call is asynchronous in most cases so you should be getting the model in a callback which is not presented in the code above.
- I dont know if fetching the collection everytime you want a model is the correct approach either? If the collection already exists you just need to get the model from the collection just using the id.
- depending on the exact use case, you might just want to pass the model as a    parameter from one  controller to the next